# What is this book about two best friends sucked into a computer playing different games, including Minecraft, and featuring a dragon world?

Tags: story-identification, books

This book is one I read when I was little. It’s about a few people who get sucked into a computer where they have to play through several different games. The only one I remember is *Minecraft*, but there are two best friends who are the main ones we follow. They have to beat the games to advance, and they get to this dragon world where dragons don’t trust humans. They find a bully from their world, and they team up to help the good dragons defeat the evil dragons and move on to the next game. Other details include: the bully wanted to kill a dragon for dragon scale armor, you keep all your items from the previous games, you can get better gear, and you have a limited number of lives.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more of the site's features.

Comment: One of the books in the [Minecraft series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/148592-gameknight999-minecraft-series)?

Comment: Around what year would "when I was little" be? Obviously post-Minecraft's release (in 2009-2011), but can you narrow it down any further?